# Cells inline-border doesn't stretch out when there is more than one line of text in one of the cells

Tags: html, css

I've got a table made from divs. It works fine when every cell has only one line of text, however, when there's more text in one of the cells, the trouble begins. The text in this cell is being wrapped to multiple lines, the inline-border of this cell is being stretched, but all other cells just freeze intact. 
The html code is:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
.trow {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.trow1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
.tcell {
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="trow1">
    <div class="tcell" style="line-height: 35px; width:30%; height:40px;">Left Stuff</div>
    <div class="tcell" style="line-height: 35px; width:40%; height:40px;">Middle Stuff</div>
    <div class="tcell" style="line-height: 35px; width:30%; height:40px;">Right Stuff</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
  </div>
  <div class="trow">
    <div class="tcell" style="width:25%;">Left Stuff</div>
    <div class="tcell" style="width:40%;">Middle Stuff</div>
    <div class="tcell" style="width:25%;">Right Stuff</div>
    <div class="tcell" style="width:10%;">R-Right StuffR-Right StuffR-Right StuffR-Right StuffR-Right StuffR-Right Stuff</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please advice what could I do. TIA.

Comment: The other cells are independent of the stretched out stuff, if you want to have them stretch change to flex or flex inline for the easiest way to do this. Otherwise there are quite a few hacky sort of ways to get it done.

Comment: Also, your CSS is basically making your code a table -- why not just use a `<table>`?

Comment: if you remove float: left from .tcell it will help with your current problem, but  will cause another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `display: table` for `trow` and `trow1`, then it looks as you want:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
.trow {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.trow1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="trow1">
    <div class="tcell" style="line-height: 35px; width:30%; height:40px;">Left Stuff</div>
    <div class="tcell" style="line-height: 35px; width:40%; height:40px;">Middle Stuff</div>
    <div class="tcell" style="line-height: 35px; width:30%; height:40px;">Right Stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="trow">
    <div class="tcell" style="width:25%;">Left Stuff</div>
    <div class="tcell" style="width:40%;">Middle Stuff</div>
    <div class="tcell" style="width:25%;">Right Stuff</div>
    <div class="tcell" style="width:10%;">R-Right StuffR-Right StuffR-Right StuffR-Right StuffR-Right StuffR-Right Stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does work now, even though right-side border is bolder than it should be, but I believe I could manage that, The most important problem is solved, thanks again.